# Can't select Multiple Dropdown with Selenium webdriver (not class Select)

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I'm having a problem with my tests with Selenium webdriver. I'm using Java. Can't select from a multiple drop-down that is not class Select. This is how the drop-down looks like:

[Drop-Down picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzsSN.jpg)

And that's the code:

```
 <div class="form-group ">
       <label for="CurrentCategoriesNomIds-selectized">Categories</label>
      <select placeholder="" multiple="multiple" id="CurrentCategoriesNomIds" name="CurrentCategoriesNomIds" tabindex="-1" class="selectized" style="display: none;">
          <option value="325" selected="selected">Education</option>
      </select>
<div class="selectize-control multi plugin-remove_button">
  <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options has-items">
    <div class="item" data-value="325">
       Education
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove" tabindex="-1" title="Remove">×</a>
    </div>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="CurrentCategoriesNomIds-selectized" style="width: 4px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;"></div>
  <div class="selectize-dropdown multi plugin-remove_button" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 800px; top: 36px; left: 0px;">
    <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
      <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="324">Agriculture</div>
      <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="298">Culture</div>
      <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="326">Employment</div>
      <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="323">Environment</div>
      <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="327">Other</div>
      <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="297">Political</div>
      <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="322">Transport</div> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>

                        </div>
```

This is how it looks like when 2 options are selected. I was wondering if I can try with KEYS but the page doesn't work like that. Haven't seen that kind of field before, and not sure how to proceed?

Comment: Could you interact with it by sending it a down arrow and sending it a space or an enter? Or by clicking on the div with the text that you are looking for (xpath for interacting with "Employment": `//*/*[contains(@class, "option") and contains(text(), "Employment")]`)?

Comment: Please paste the code in the question instead of making a screenshot of your code.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @Maharkus Thanks, I will, I'm having problems with formatting it correct.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks, I will.

Comment: @JulianaGeorgieva Do publish your your code trials so instead of enforcing an answer on you, volunteers can explain you where you were wrong.

Comment: @KyleFairns The locator works, and I can use arrows up and down and enter to pick option after i click on the field, will try that too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on dropdown using this code :

```
   public static  void selectOption(WebDriver driver, String optionName) {
        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='selectize-dropdoun-content']//div[@class='option']"));
        options.forEach(option -> {
            if (option.getAttribute("innerText").equals(optionName)) {
                Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                actions.moveToElement(option).click().build().perform();
            }
        });
    }
```

and then use like this:

```
String option = "Education";
selectOption(driver,option);
```

Hope that helps you:)

Adding screenshot for what I have tried on website : https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html
[image]

Comment: JUnit said the test passed but the field is empty. During the test, it stopped there for a while and continued without selecting an option.

Comment: use this xpath " //div[@class='selectize-dropdown-content']//div[@class='option']".'

Comment: tried, the same. Test passed but the field is empty.

Comment: may be your click is not working properly. sometimes it happens. try clicking using JavaScriptExecutor or Actions Class

Comment: updated answer and it will work for you. please do let me know after trying that. I have tested it on https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Comment: Again the same, it stops there for a moment and then continue and pass the test. I tried that locator and a different one //*[@id="myform"]//div[@class='selectize-dropdown-content']//div[@class='option'] but still the same. 
I will try JavaScriptExecutor and tell you if it might work. 
I checked out the link you gave and the dropdown there looks the same but is class Select, and mine is not. And there it is <option value="">Skills</option>
and on my site it's <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="324">Agriculture</div>

Comment: no it is also div there when you click on state input box the dropdown elements are divs and not select

Comment: ping me at sandpdangi13@gmail.com for any help.

Comment: It worked, I found the problem. The options were not visible before you click on the field :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't much use Java, so I'll be writing some pseudo code for this that should give you an outline on how to achieve it (but may not run as written).

```
public static void selectOptionFromSelectizeDropdown(String optionText, String dropdown){
   boolean completed = false;
   int numberOfOptions = driver.findElements(By.css(dropdown + " .option")).length
   for(int i = 0; i < numberOfOptions && completed === false; i++){
       // Check if it's displayed, if it is, HUZZAH! Click the option
       if(driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*/*[contains(@class, "option") and contains(text(), "'+optionText+'")])')).isDisplayed()){
           driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*/*[contains(@class, "option") and contains(text(), "'+optionText+'")])')).click();
           completed === true;
           break;
       } else {
           // In case there are many options, and you have to scroll through them.
           int x = 0;
           while(x <= 6){
              driver.findElement(By.css(dropdown)).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
              i++;
           }
       }
       if(i===numberOfOptions - 1){
          throw new Error("Option Not Found");
       }
   }
}

selectOptionFromSelectizeDropdown("Education", ".selectize-dropdown-content");
```

If this doesn't work, I'd recommend changing the `click()` to a `sendKeys(Key.ENTER)` to see if that would work.

**Explanation**

Will loop through, seeing if the option is displayed on the page. If not, will scroll down x times, and check again, until the option is found.

If it reaches the number of options inside the box, it will throw an error.

Comment: Hey, thanks I haven't tried that yet, but I will and tell you if it works.